# Taking Values from HTML and returning another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not sure how to take 2 inputs and return another value. Also is there any way for me to be able to tell where my code is going wrong? I'm still trying to understand all the nuances of how HTML and Javascript work together. I'm currently reading through Eloquent javascript but i'm always looking for suggested resources.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Wilks</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wilks.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="bodyWeight">Weight:</label> 
            <input id="bodyWeight" type="number" placeholder="Pounds">
            <label for="Big 3 Total">Big 3 Total:</label>
            <input id="liftTotal" type="number" placeholder="800" >
            <button onclick="wilksCalculator(bodyWeight, liftTotal)">Analyze</button>
        </p>
        <p>Wilks Coefficient: <span id="outputWilks"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

// wilks.js

```
var a =-216.0475144;
var b =16.2606339;
var c =-0.002388645;
var d =-0.00113732;
var e =7.01863E-06;
var f =-1.291E-08;
var x = document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value;
var inputTotal = document.getElementById("liftTotal").vaule;
//var outputWilks;

function wilksCalculator(bodyWeight, liftTotal) {
    bodyWeight = x;
    return (liftTotal * (500/((a+b*x)+(c(Math.pow(x,2)))+(d+(Math.pow(x,3)))+(e+(Math.pow(x,4)))+(f(Math.pow(x,5))))));

}

var wilks = document.getElementById("outputWilks").innerHTML;
if (wilks) {
    wilks.onsubmit = function () {
        this.wilks.value = wilksCalculator(this.bodyWeight.value, 
        this.liftTotal.value);
        return false;
    };
}

wilksCalculator();
```

Comment: "is there any way for me to be able to tell where my code is going wrong?" Check the console for errors.

Comment: Syntax typo: vaule instead of value.

Comment: there is a typo on 2nd last line **vaule** instead of **value** and also paste the function wilksCalculator for further guidance

Comment: A string (the output of `.innerHTML`) does not have an `onsubmit` property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<p>
   <label for="bodyWeight">Weight:</label>  
<input id="bodyWeight" type="number" placeholder="Pounds"**/>**
<label for="Big 3 Total">Big 3 Total:</label>
<input id="liftTotal" type="number" placeholder="800" **/>**
<button onclick="wilksCalculator(bodyWeight, liftTotal)">Analyze</button>
</p>
<p>Wilks Coefficient: <span id="outputWilks"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add event listeners, then get values and calculate.

Note some errors in your function `c(..` would be a function call, assumed you wanted to multiply.  Same with `f`.,  Check the formula.

Took the variables out of global scope and put in the function.  Fixed some typos.

```js
function wilksCalculator(bodyWeight, liftTotal) {
  var a = -216.0475144;
  var b = 16.2606339;
  var c = -0.002388645;
  var d = -0.00113732;
  var e = 7.01863E-06;
  var f = -1.291E-08;
  var x = bodyWeight;
  return (liftTotal * (500 / ((a + b * x) + (c * (Math.pow(x, 2))) + (d + (Math.pow(x, 3))) + (e + (Math.pow(x, 4))) + (f * (Math.pow(x, 5))))));

}

function wilksClick() {
  var wilks = document.getElementById("outputWilks");
  var bodyWeight = document.getElementById("bodyWeight").value;
  var liftTotal = document.getElementById("liftTotal").value;
  wilks.innerHTML = wilksCalculator(bodyWeight, liftTotal);
  return false;
}
var el = document.getElementById("calculate-wilks");
el.addEventListener("click", wilksClick, false);
```

```html
<body>
  <p>
    <label for="bodyWeight">Weight:</label>
    <input id="bodyWeight" type="number" placeholder="Pounds">
    <label for="liftTotal">Big 3 Total:</label>
    <input id="liftTotal" type="number" placeholder="800">
    <button id="calculate-wilks">Analyze</button>
  </p>
  <p>Wilks Coefficient: <span id="outputWilks"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Note I did nothing about validating the input (range, numeric etc), just used it.